# Using useState to create a slider for an object with arrays

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a slider for an object (workout) that updates the exercise that is shown based on an index. The object has a collection of objects, and each object has an array inside it. The idea was to go to the next or the previous exercise. I know that setState works asynchronously and in this case I should use the useEffect hook too, but I coudn't figure it out. I've created some states to pass through the values but didn't work. Is there something wrong with my logic? It can be done using only the useState and useEffect hooks? Sorry if it seems dumb but I'd really appreciate some advice. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**: I did a modification in my code and now it is working as expected almost. The next button is working, but the prev button, in the condition case where I check if the value is 0, to prevent the access of a negative index in the array, it is not. So, my question now is: *how can I do this validation before assigning the negative value*? Thanks in advance!

Here are the files. The object I'm trying to slide through:

```
{
  name: "Pernas 1",
  workoutObs: "entre o aquecimento e os ciclos 1' a 1'30'' de descanso.",
  cycles: [
    {
      series: "2",
      exercises: [
        {
          name: "Agachamento com salto",
          reps: "20"
        }
      ],
      cycleObs: "Aquecimento."
    },
    {
      series: "4",
      exercises: [
        {
          name: "Agachamento com barra guiada/Smith",
          reps: "15"
        },
        {
          name: "Agachamento com barra guiada/Smith",
          reps: "12"
        },
        {
          name: "Agachamento com barra guiada/Smith",
          reps: "10"
        },
        {
          name: "Agachamento com barra guiada/Smith",
          reps: "8"
        }
      ],
      cycleObs: "Descida controlada sem arrancos e sem descer de uma vez."
    },
    {
      series: "3",
      exercises: [
        {
          name: "Leg Press 45",
          reps: ""
        },
        {
          name: "Agachamento livre parcial",
          reps: "10"
        }
      ],
      cycleObs:
        "pés abertos, pés fechados, agachamento parcial com anilha/alteres."
    },
    {
      series: "3",
      exercises: [
        {
          name: "Cadeira adutora",
          reps: ""
        },
        {
          name: "Avanço/passada com halteres",
          reps: ""
        },
        {
          name: "Panturrilha livre unilateral",
          reps: ""
        }
      ],
      cycleObs: "panturrilha - 10 cada perna + 10 bilateral."
    },
    {
      series: "4",
      exercises: [
        {
          name: "Cadeira extensora",
          reps: ""
        }
      ],
      cycleObs: "10 carga média/alta + 08 carga máxima."
    },
    {
      series: 0,
      exercises: [
        {
          name: "HIIT",
          reps: "5"
        },
        {
          name: "ABS pedalada",
          reps: "30"
        },
        {
          name: "bike",
          reps: "30"
        }
      ],
      cycleObs: "sem descanso entre a bike e o abdominal."
    }
  ]
}
```

And the component that receives the object (updated):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'


const Workout = () => {
  
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const workout = state;

  const [ outerIndex, setOuterIndex ] = useState(0);
  const [ innerIndex, setInnerIndex ] = useState(0);

  //modification: created consts to swap between cycles and exercises
  const currentCycle = workout.cycles[outerIndex];
  const currentExercise = currentCycle.exercises[innerIndex];

  //modification: the boolean variables to disable the buttons if the edge of the array is reached
  const maxLimit = (innerIndex+1 == currentCycle.exercises.length) 
                    && (outerIndex+1 == workout.cycles.length) 
                    ? true : false;
  
  const minLimit = (innerIndex == 0) && (outerIndex == 0) ? true : false;

  const nextIndex = () => {
    if((innerIndex+1) == currentCycle.exercises.length){
      setOuterIndex(outerIndex+1);
      setInnerIndex(0);
    }
    else{
      setInnerIndex(innerIndex+1);
    }
  }
  
  const prevIndex = () => {
    if(innerIndex == 0){
      setOuterIndex(outerIndex-1);
      setInnerIndex(currentCycle.exercises.lengh-1);
    }
    else{
      setInnerIndex(innerIndex-1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <section id="workout-container">
      <h3>{workout.name}</h3>
      <aside>Orientações:{workout.workoutObs}</aside>
      <button onClick={prevIndex} disabled={minLimit}>prev</button>
      <button onClick={nextIndex} disabled={maxLimit}>next</button>
      <div className='cycle-item'>
        <h4>Ciclo {outerIndex+1} - {currentCycle.series}x</h4>
        <div className='exercise-item'>
          <p>{currentExercise.name}</p>
          <p>reps.:{currentExercise.reps}</p>
        </div>
        <p>{currentCycle.cycleObs}</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Workout;
```

I removed useEffect hook because I was doing it wrong. Thanks for all the help!